Extract passwords and cookies from Chrome folder in macos
I've recently had a problem with my ten years old macbook pro retina and I've decided to buy a new one m3 chip. At the moment I'm looking for a way to recover chrome cookies and password, I was able to extract the Chrome folder from the other macOS, but at the moment I've tried different scripts to try recover the passwords but with no success. At this point I want to create a script that can read from the Sqlite databases and decrypt the informations. Can anyone point me into the correct direction, I know that inside the Local state file there are the needed informations, but can I read the file in nodejs and then decrypt sqlite db?

Why not just transfer the raw config files/databases (& I think there's a keychain entry with the encryption password)? Or better yet, use Apple's Migration Assistant to transfer your whole account? In any case, Stackoverflow is for questions about programming, not general computer usage; Ask Different and Superuser are better places for things like this. Before asking, search for previous relevant questions.

@GordonDavisson, I saw this question, my main problem is that I've used the migration assistant, but I'm on an apple chip now and the migration didn't helped. Not sure if I need to copy the whole profile from the external macos hd, it is a macos installed on an intel machine. Thank you for the suggesion, I will ask also there
